# Polymer or jQuery to attach custom Behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer-1.0

I was thinking of modifying an existing website using polymer /jquery in a way that I can keep existing structure as it is and just add some logic using Jquery or Polymer to a set of elements say all the **anchor tags** will have on click feature to show an popover with form which can modify the existing look and content for that specific tag.

So the main concern is should I go with jquery (manipulating the Dom and using some third party libraries like watch.js and bottle.js to get 2-way binding and dependency injection ) or should I go ahead with creating a set of web-components and then replacing them in my website.

Is it possible to add custom behaviors to existing tags using polymer,if that can be done then I can use that as I have binding dependency injection inbuilt in polymer 1.0.

I mean this is similar to angular directives whereby we can attach a scope and set of methods to that element along with some styling and html code .

```
<div my-custom-behavior ></div>
//above sample will attach suppose a popover to my div with a form which can be submitted to change the values in that div element
```

Can something similar be done in Polymer 1.0 or jQuery ?

Comment: Can you please explain your question more clearly. What do you mean by JS node?

Answer (score 0):

use `appendChild()` method.try this

```js
var parent=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","p");
var img=document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","img");
img.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg');
parent.appendChild(img);
document.body.appendChild(parent);
```